# Drupal 6 - creating full page content with no sidebars within

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-blocks

Hi im trying to create full page content with no sidebars within Drupal 6. I have created a Block that takes up the full page and turned off other blocks but by any chance does someone know how to shut off the main page content? Or is there another way about this?

Here is the page:
http://www.blackrockec.ie/content/how-grow-wild-flowers-seeds

The block is working perfectly, but below it is the main page content and I want this turned off,
Any help would be very appreciated!!!

I have turned off the title but the white space below still exists.

Comment: can u check ur tpl file if $content is printed twice?

Comment: Just checked, no its not :(

Comment: can you share your tpl file?

Comment: think $title is getting printed twice, can u comment $title and check?

Comment: I dont think it would be to do with the tpl file, this is only for one of the pages so if I changed that file it would be for all the pages, I only want to show the block I have created, so I just need to turn off the main page, so the settings for this should be somewhere within Drupal admin

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: This is basically what im trying todo: http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/creating-full-page-content-no-sidebars but he dosent say how to turn off the main page?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.
I believe you can put "<none>" as the block title (leave out the quotes) and the block title will not appear on the page.

Comment: Hi tried that, it still showed as <none>, but if I got that to work, how do I get rid of the white space below the title or will that not show once the title is gone?

Comment: @vimal any other suggestions??? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could gather using the [link](http://www.blackrockec.ie/content/how-grow-wild-flowers-seeds) provided here are a few possible solutions that might be of help.

1. **Check node body** From the source of the link provided here the node id of the troublemaker is 292. Using any role in the site that has administrative access to edit content visit http://www.blackrockec.ie/node/292/edit to check the body of the node. There's a possibility of php code being used in some cases to display body content where your site breadcrumb link could be printed.
2. **Check the template file used to render content** If this specific 'node' is of a different type in comparison with the other nodes say the next [content](http://www.blackrockec.ie/content/tropical-garden-bottle) in your site, (i-e) if the node with the problem is of type page and the others are of stories you might want to double check the respective node template from which it could be possibly rendered to debug the issue. The general naming convention would be node-nodetype.tpl.php in your theme, so for a page you might consider checking node-page.tpl.php to troubleshoot the problem.
3. **Create a template to affect the display of this specific node** In case you are certain all of your content are of the same type and that your template is foolproof would suggest creating a specific template that would affect this node alone to check there's no other module's intervention in this. Going by core drupal's template naming conventions this would be page-node-[nodeid].tpl.php, in your case likely create page-node-292.tpl.php in your theme and comment out code where you would have `print $breadcrumb` and `print $content` and check if that affects your page display after clearing the cache. *Note: This is a hackish method which I would not approve unless used for troubleshooting the issue*
4. **Display Suite** Consider using contributed modules specifically [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) with [Node Display](https://drupal.org/project/nd) to control every aspect of your node content. They provide the ability to control attributes of the node at a very granular level with a wonderful UI that non-developers could be trained easily and master. Also extensive help guides and videos to help implement them make them favourites.

Please do update the question in case there might be any modules being used related to node display that might shed more light on the issue and hope the suggestions help.

Comment: Hi thank you so much The Display Suite worked a treat! thank you!